# Word for stupid and happy?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, idiom-requests

Is there a **formal** a word or phrase that refers to or describes a blissful yet idiotic person? Preferably a **one word** way to say "stupidly happy", but I'm open to idioms as well.

For example, a word that describes the kind of person who would ask "Why don't homeless people just buy themselves a house?" Someone who is always carefree, and cannot comprehend the concept of stress or difficulty.

I specifically want to describe a fat and wealthy British gentleman from the 1800s. Google was not helpful, it only yielded slang and references to a movie from 2014.

Comment: I guess in French, they are "imbeciles heureux".

Comment: The man from la Manchester?

Comment: There is the idiom "fat, dumb, and happy" (though not exactly an 1800s term).

Comment: There is [_kluck_](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nJ-IUpAd_5UC&pg=PA21&dq=kluck+dictionary+dumb&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLysCliYbYAhXqQt8KHfmlAwEQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=kluck%20&f=false) (meaning _dumb and happy_) from Flapper slang.

Comment: @ermanen thank you, but I am trying to refrain from slang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One phrase to consider might be **blissfully ignorant**. It doesn't necessarily imply that the person is always "happy", but it describes a person who is content to be unaware of the unpleasant realities of a given situation.

(Edit: I know this is not a single word answer; the original question asked for a word or phrase.)

Answer (score 2):

**Quixotic** may fit here to some extent, though it doesn't necessarily imply that the person is happy, just ignorantly optimistic.

> [quixotic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quixotic) (adj.) - Extremely idealistic; unrealistic and impractical.

Answer (score 1):

**Punchinello**

> Pierrot's movements and attitudes are chiefly in perpendiculars and parallels; so is his figure and dress. **Punchinello** is droll by being the reverse of all elegance, both as to movement and figure; the beauty of variety is totally and comically excluded from this character in every respect ...

Anecdotes of Mr. Hogarth: And Explanatory Descriptions of the Plates of Hogarth restored, by William Hogarth, 1803

> another name for punch(4).
>   archaic - a short, stout, comical-looking person.

"Puncinello" Dictionary.com:

> 1 capitalized : a fat short humpbacked clown or buffoon in Italian puppet shows
>   2 plural punchinellos : a squat grotesque person

"Punchinello." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Dec. 2017.

Comment: Although this is not the word I am looking for, it does fit a fat wealthy British man. I am very likely to use this in addition to the word I'm searching for =)